# Hidden form field Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Sonata Admin bundle to create admin for one of my sites. I have a form and it has many fields. I have a date field and I want this to get auto saved to database when saving the form. Means I want the date field to be hidden from the user but the date should get saved. How can I do this..?? I have tried with the hidden form type, but it was of no use. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First remove **datefield** in **configureFormFields()** function

you can use **prePersist()** and **preUpdate()** method in Admin Class

```
     public function prePersist($data) {
             $data->setDateField(date);
     }
     public function preUpdate($data) {
             $data->setDateField(date);
     }
```

In your Entitie datefield called **startDate**.

So, you can change **setDateField()** to **setStartDate()** in **prePersist()** or **preUpdate()**

Comment: Thanks @M.B Kakadiya. But I want this functionality in embedded admins. How can I do this? Right now I am not able to update the child table dates.

Answer (score 1):

In the AdminClass, you have `preUpdate()` and `prePersist()` methods where you can set your date value.

You can also use StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst and the Timestampable Extension

> **Timestampable** - updates date fields on create, update and even
>   property change.